# HDRI strange double rotation with glass shader

Tags: eevee-render-engine, glass, artifacts, hdri, reflection

I am using EEVEE and when I see in render mode through a glass there is a transparent "copy" of the environment image's reflection but with a different rotation. The problem is caused by the glass shader, the material is literally only the glass node.

another problem that appear if I change the IOR of the glass node is a vertical line.

The window is inside a closed room, so the copy of the reflection is not the other side of the hdri

Solved:  Martynas Žiemys comment has the solution

How can I resolve this?
Here the gif of the problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/osga2.jpg

Comment: "the copy of the reflection is not the other side of the hdri" - how do you know? This seems exactly like a reflection. EEVEE does not take the room into consideration when rendering reflections unless you use refelection cubemaps.

Comment: I didn't know that! the room was closed so it couldn't be the other side of the hdri,it seems that I was wrong. thank you for the tip, I'll look the reflection cubemaps :)